# Is delete necessary when the variable is local?

Tags: c++

If I were to allocate new memory for a local character array in a function using "new", would it be necessary to use delete prior to the function return?

Wouldn't it automatically be deleted after the function return anyway?

Comment: Consider adding some supporting code, as it's easier to see at a glance than "If I were to allocate .. using new, ..". I also hope someone says something about variables vs objects.

Comment: You should almost never use `new` for a local variable anyway. Use a value object instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary: if you allocate something on the dynamic store with `new` or `new[]`, the compiler has no idea that you have no plans to pass the allocated object along after the function returns, so it is your responsibility to call `delete` (or `delete[]`) to free the object that you have allocated.

You can use [`unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to avoid calling the `delete` explicitly, but the call will be made by the destructor of `unique_ptr<T>` on your behalf.

Comment: Given that the OP is about to allocate a dynamic *array*, it would seem apposite to mention `unique_ptr<T[]>` as well, which calls the correct `delete[]` to destroy the array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, variables allocated with `new` *aren't* automatically freed up when the funciton returns, and still need to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes, yes, yes, yes. Unless you are using a smart pointer such as `auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`, you must use `delete` to deallocate the memory.

Because `new` allocates on the heap, which is not dependent on the current stack frame, the memory is not dealocated when C++ destroys the current stack frame. If you use `new`, you ALWAYS have to use `delete`. Period.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated (but still applicable to this use case) and `shared_ptr` is overkill for this situation. `unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` are better suited for this purpose.

Comment: @Prætorian: Good suggestion. I know that `auro_ptr` is deprecated, I just wanted a few examples of smart pointer.